# Adding key value pair (value from an array) to specific objects in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects:

```
chachters = [{name: "Frodo", race: "hobitt", age: 111}, 
             {name: "Gandalf", race: "human", age: 2019}],
             {name: "Aragorn", race: "elf", age: 40}];
```

and an array of strings.

```
swords = ["Sting","Glamdring","Anduril"];
```

I want to add a key-value pair to the objects in 'characters' so the correct sword is assigned to the correct character. The indexes match in that swords[0] needs to be added to the value in charachrers[0]:

Here's what I'd like characters to look like:

```
 chachters =[{name:"Frodo", race:"hobitt", age:111,sword:"Sting"}, 
             {name:"Gandalf",race:"human",age:2019,sword:"Glamdring"}],
             {name:"Aragorn",race:"elf",age:40,sword:"Anduril"}];
```

Please help. The fait of middle earth depends on it.

Comment: Plenty of people have answered how to do what you asked so I won't do the same. But rather than copy the swords into the characters objects, might it be beneficial to retain it as a separate collection of sword objects and for the current holder of a sword to just store the index reference of their sword? Do swords ever change change owners? Your approach looks like a one-off data tidy-up, and not an ideal way to store 2 separate lists that actually have a 1-to-1 relationship.

Comment: I agree with @Raith. If you do it the way you are doing, then assuming you `chachters` array contains **100** objects, the `swords` will also have **100** strings, **WITH DUPLICATES** _(Because you logically won't have 100 different types of swords)_. Something like: `["Sting", Glamdring", "Anduril", "Sting", "Anduril", ... ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use #array.forEach and for each object of array add extra key with the value from swords array.

Working snippet (This way, it will do the changes directly in the original array):

```js
let chachters = [
      {name: "Frodo", race: "hobitt", age: 111}, 
      {name: "Gandalf", race: "human", age: 2019},
      {name: "Aragorn", race: "elf", age: 40}];

let swords = ["Sting","Glamdring","Anduril"];

chachters.forEach((el,i) => {
     el.sword = swords[i];
})

console.log('chachters = ', chachters);
```

If `chachters` is a state array and you are updating the state then use this way:

```js
let chachters = [
      {name: "Frodo", race: "hobitt", age: 111}, 
      {name: "Gandalf", race: "human", age: 2019},
      {name: "Aragorn", race: "elf", age: 40}];

let swords = ["Sting","Glamdring","Anduril"];

let newchachters = chachters.map((el,i) => ({...el, sword: swords[i]}))

console.log('chachters = ', chachters);
console.log('newchachters = ', newchachters);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `map` and `Object.assign`:

```js
var chachters = [{name: "Frodo", race: "hobitt", age: 111}, 
             {name: "Gandalf", race: "human", age: 2019},
             {name: "Aragorn", race: "elf", age: 40}],
    swords = ["Sting","Glamdring","Anduril"];

var result = chachters.map( (obj, i) => Object.assign({ sword: swords[i] }, obj) );
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `array#map` with `spread syntax`. Add a sword to a character based on the index.

```js
const chachters = [{name: "Frodo", race: "hobitt", age: 111}, {name: "Gandalf", race: "human", age: 2019},       {name: "Aragorn", race: "elf", age: 40}],
      swords = ["Sting","Glamdring","Anduril"],
      result = chachters.map((o,i) => ({...o, sword: swords[i]}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function to append the array of strings to the array of objects;

**For example:**

This function will be used to append the array of strings to the array of object

```
function appendObjTo(swords, chachters ) {
        return Object.freeze(swords.concat(chachters ));
    }
```

From what you defined:

```
  swords = ["Sting","Glamdring","Anduril"];
        const chachters = [{name: "Frodo", race: "hobitt", age: 111}, 
             {name: "Gandalf", race: "human", age: 2019},
             {name: "Aragorn", race: "elf", age: 40}];

        const newChachters = appendObjTo(swords, chachters);
```

Answer (score 1):

Allow me to try. I'm not so familiar with .map() :P

```js
var characters = [
    {name: "Frodo", race: "hobitt", age: 111}, 
    {name: "Gandalf", race: "human", age: 2019},
    {name: "Aragorn", race: "elf", age: 40}
];
var swords = ["Sting", "Glamdring", "Anduril"];

var charactersWithSwords = characters.map(function (character, index) {
    character.swords = swords[index];
    return character;
});

console.log(charactersWithSwords);
```

Result:

```
> Array [Object { name: "Frodo", race: "hobitt", age: 111, swords: "Sting" }, Object { name: "Gandalf", race: "human", age: 2019, swords: "Glamdring" }, Object { name: "Aragorn", race: "elf", age: 40, swords: "Anduril" }]
```